# CMake doesn't set LangVersion for C# project

Tags: c#, cmake

I'm trying to generate C# project for *Visual Studio 2017* with a *CMake 3.16.3*, but I'm having problems setting C# language version.
Even if I'm specifying it at top of CMakeLists.txt file as such:

```
target_compile_options(<MyApp> PRIVATE "/langversion:latest")
```

Or like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:latest")
```

Inside the *.csproj file it is always set like this:

```xml
<Project>
    ...
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <AdditionalOptions>/langversion:latest</AdditionalOptions>
        ...
        <LangVersion>3</LangVersion>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

So no matter what value I put there, **it is always version 3** (which is minimum version). Without specifying language version, it set to default and that is latestMajor, Version 7.0.

Only way around this problem so far is to create **[Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)** file inside build folder. And it looks like this:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm quite new with CMake and its documentation is quite complex, so I probably have missed some steps. Or is this a bug in CMake and has anyone had any better solutions for this problem?

Here is link for [projects Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/Sipir94/genereate-csharp-project-with-cmake)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? A singe C# file a small CMake file should be enough. But as far as I know, C# is no supported language from CMake.

Comment: I added example project to gitlab. The link is at bottom of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with *Visual Studio 2017*. By default *Visual Studio 2019* determines C# language version based on framework version. [Here is the Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

tl;dr Basically just upgrade to *Visual Studio 2019*

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of CMake that has been only recently fixed in version 3.17.0 . 
You need to install CMake version 3.17 and generate the solutions from the command line.

See [this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17674) in the CMake issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I updated the CMake from 3.16.3 to 3.17.0, but the same problem still exists. Now the language version is always latestMajor, no matter what I specify in CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS or in target_compile_options.

Comment: Are you clearing the cache, i.e. deleting CMakeCache.txt from the build directory after applying your changes? `CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS` is cached and won't be updated otherwise.

Comment: Yes I'm deleting whole build folder that contains CMakeCache.txt file.

Comment: Just tested your project. For the current state in the `csproj` file no `LangVersion` is set, as you are forcing to use `/langversion:latest`. If I change that to `/langversion:5` , delete the build folder and rerun cmake command an entry with `<LangVersion>5</LangVersion>` is added, so everything seems to work for me as you expect. I am using Visual Studio 2019. My cmake command was `cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"`.

Comment: Interesting, when you set `/langversion:7` or newer the `<LangVersion></LangVersion>` property disappears and set it to `<AdditionalOptions>/langversion:"7 or newer"</AdditionalOptions>`. I was able to set version 5 and 6, that I tried.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2019 solved my problem. Now by default it determines language version based on framework version. [With all .NET Framework versions language version is 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language) (default value shall be used):

> set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:default")

Or just set the property VS_GLOBAL_LangVersion to 8.0 (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434706/7539232)):

> set_property(TARGET myLib PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_LangVersion "8.0")