# Reference Path in Visual Studio not working when I unload the project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solution, assembly-reference-path

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` project with one solution and 52 projects in the same solution. As you know, It takes long time to build whole solution. So I decided to unload some of the projects until there is some change or sprint task in the code in the unloaded project. However we are a team and use TFS version control and we need to use update unloaded assembly. So I have a build server that makes me sure whenever somebody starts to check-in (for example -> `C:\bin` in our network) the last version of all assembly can be found there.

I added `C:\bin` path as Reference Path to the UI Project (main project of the solution) of the solution and I expect when some projects is unloaded the reference comes to visual studio from the build server path (`C:\bin`) otherwise the reference of the project comes to Visual Studio from the nested project (not from build server).

[image]

But the reference can not be found when the project is unloaded:

[image]

And my Build server contains the assembly:

[image]

Comment: If you unload the projects, then the build will fail because other projects have dependency on the unloaded project. There are 2 ways to add a reference, you can either add a reference to another project or you can add a reference to the project DLL. So one solution would be to split your solution to let's say 2 solutions... then build your solution one and add the dependencies as a DLL files... even more elegant would be to put your DLLs in Nuget, and install them as Nuget packages.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468997/switch-between-source-code-and-precompiled-binaries/61517579#61517579) might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to use Reference Paths in Visual Studio As I show in the picture

Comment: How do I know the project is unloaded? I want to use condition in Reference tag in web.config to switch between class library (.dll) and debugable project

Comment: You can't switch between between dll and project, the question that I have put in the comment above is asking about exactly the same thing, I think it would answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way (only in Visual Studio 2019) to unload projects and however use updated class library of unloaded projects. And thanks to [Hooman Bahreini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8211528/hooman-bahreini) for his idea of using two separated solutions.

The way is that, there is a feature of Visual Studio 2019 that we can `Save As Solution Filter` which is in ***.slnf*** extensions. So I can unload some of my projects and check-in ***.slnf*** file via my source control (like tfs). So I have two solutions Now, one is ***.sln*** which is contains all of projects and the other one is ***.slnf*** which is unloaded some of projects in it.

The things can we do is that whenever I want to get my project I have to use ***.sln*** file and builds that and then close the file and then open the ***.slnf*** file (I'm sure that I have updated class library of unloaded projects) and do my task and `check-in` my changes.